# internationalization in JSP/Spring with nested keys

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

Looking for a clean internationalization method which allows for nested keys.

e.g. Message = Please check your boot for the tools.
Now word boot is used in 100s of strings across s/w, and when I go to client X he says change boot with trunk. So would like to create language files with key embedded in value like

message = Please check your {boot} for the tools.
boot = trunk

It will be a SaaS app and we'll allow user to change the strings through web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a good idea:

- how do you know which words or sequences of words are susceptible to change before they actually change?
- what if client X wants to remove "Please" from the sentence?
- how do you plan to deal with plural forms, varying grammar rules, genre differences between words, etc. (all this in several different languages)?

IMHO, either your system is simplistic, but will fit the bill in 2% of the cases, or it will be very complex, a nightmare to use and configure, and you'll lose time and readability for a problem that happens very rarely anyway and can be fixed with ad hoc search/replace.

If the simplistic approach suits you, I would just need special markup to identify tokens (`@boot@`, for example), and do the replacements during the build of the application, using Ant's [replace task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) for example.

Comment: this was one requirement, plurals, grammar and all can be handled as usual. In my last company's school software all clients were using English, but with subtle nomenclature difference e.g. Grade is called Class in some schools, we don't want to change it in 100s of strings and create a maintenance issue.

Comment: I agree with JB Nizet on this, I'm not sure this is a good idea. Either you may generate the final properties that will be used in your application during build. So you would have a property file with common tokens that would get replaced in the properties uppond build, using Maven or ant.

Comment: It will be a SaaS app and we'll allow user to change the strings through web interface, so would prefer some packaged solution, but will consider it, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a **Concatenation** - second most common Internationalization defect. In other words, don't do that. It is better to duplicate this 100 strings - it is fairly easy with valid tools (like text editor that supports Regular Expressions) instead of concatenating the strings.

### The longer explanation why:

1. Many (if not the most) languages have the concept of [Inflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection), that is the word you want to concatenate might need to be translated into few ***different*** forms.
2. Often translation depends on the context. If the word must be translated exactly as is (just the form changes), it is not necessary the case with... the context itself. It is not a theory, consider following example.
   We had a string in resources like this "{0} has been switched {1}" which was resolved to "[some program] | [some function] has been switched [on] | [off]". The problem was, when we wanted to translate it correctly to Polish (just an example, happens in many other languages), it should be different depending on whether it was a program or a function. Just because a program is masculine ("**Program** [jakiś program] został [włączony] | [wyłączony]") and function is feminine ("**Funkcja** [jakaś funkcja] został****a**** [włączon****a****] | [wyłączon****a****]").
   Not only the form of words needed to change, but the entire context (see added words)!
   It is not feasible with concatenations. Some of you may say "what about disk footprint?". Well, space is cheap nowadays, it is just the case what is right or wrong. Concatenating words just to save few kilobytes is ***wrong*** and will lead to serious Localizability problems.
3. Sometimes, Inflection is not a problem, but you need to change the [mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood) say from indicative to imperative, depending on the context. That makes for a different translation.

If you really need to use message formatting, I'd suggest to use it for numbers, currencies and dates only (remember about valid regional formatting!).

Comment: Actually I want to avoid concatenation, as any nested keys will be part of language file only. Also inflection, mood and context will be handled as in all frameworks. I need just to handle simple cases where few words in same language have very common synonyms and we do not want to create lang files for each client with 100s of string
e.g. client file with three entries class=grade;  classes=grades; teacher=educator is much easier to create/manage then a file with 100s of strings.

Comment: If you are looking to create a thesaurus, ResourceBundles are definitely not good place to do that. Right now, from what I understand, you would like to replace certain words with others, so that you can multiply sentences with that synonyms, right? If this is a case, my points are still valid, because whole sentences would need to be translated differently depending on things above and ***gender*** which I forgot to add to the list. There is no way to construct sentences this way, if these sentences need to be translated, sorry.

Comment: Not exactly synonyms, but different nomenclature used by different clients, I will continue using gender as used in the framework. I need to handle simple scenarios wherein one school uses word class and another grade. I want this change to be independent of code and easily maintainable. Capitalization to classes and grades will be handled as standard in framework.